Scrape google knowledge graph with Rselenium
I am trying to access the elements on the rhs of the google search, sometimes called the knowledge graph. In particular I am interested in the short bio (normally a wikipedia snippet) and the external links to personal website and social media links.
It seems to be possible to do this directly with an API such as SerpAPI but unfortunately it is not integrated into R. I have tried to grab the links with SelectorGadget using both class, id, and xpath but none seem to work. The problem seems to be that whatever I do, I always end up with the total list of URLs (including the ones in the main search page, on lhs).

rD = rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever = "123.0.6312.105", verbose = F, port = free_port(), check = FALSE)
  remDr <- rD[["client"]]
  goto_url = paste("https://www.google.com/search?q=", URLencode("Paolo Giordano"))
  remDr$navigate(goto_url)
  
  # Accept cookies
  remDr$switchToFrame("ect-cookie-dialog")
  btn1 <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", 'L2AGLb')
  btn1$clickElement()
  
  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".kno-rdesc")  # Adjust this selector based on the actual content class
  bio_snippet <- webElem$getElementText()[[1]]
  bio_snippet <- gsub("^Description\\s+|\\s+Wikipedia$", "", bio_snippet)
  # this is ok 
    
  rhs = remDr$findElement(using = "id", "rhs")
  links = rhs$findElement(using = "class", "sATSHe")
  
  page_source = links$getPageSource()
  html_source = read_html(page_source |> unlist())
  
  
  html_source |> html_elements("a") |> html_attr("href")

Given this code, instead of the 3 or 4 urls I expect, I end up with around 150, that is all urls that appear for the google search. I've tried using different selector such as
remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", ".sATSHe a")

or
 rhs <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="_yngnZt_vD6K8i-gPgYa10AI_55"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/g-link/a')

but none seem to isolate the RHS.

You've tried the (overcomplicated) following XPath :
//*[@id="_yngnZt_vD6K8i-gPgYa10AI_55"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/g-link/a

It doesn't work since the value of @id attribute keeps changing when you refresh the page.
You have to be specific but not too much.
The following XPath will target the links you're looking for :
//div[contains(@data-attrid,"media presence")]//a

You can give it a new try with RSelenium (without using rvest).
Or using rvest during all the process. Something like :
### Packages
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

### Setuping rvest
Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
)

### Declaring the persons we're working with
persons=c("Paolo Giordano",
          "Saverio Costanzo",
          "Anthony Julian Tamburri",
          "Sergio Albeverio",
          "Joseph Tusiani")

### Building URLs
### We use "hl=it" since we're working with italian people
### Results for description field will be in italian or in english
persons_fix=paste0("https://www.google.com/search?hl=it&q=",str_replace_all(persons,"\\s","\\+"))

### Writing the function to get the data with custom XPath
### Multiple links will be separated with a "|"
### For description field we don't accept automated translation and get the one from original source
rhs=function(x,y){
  ob=read_html_live(x)
  p1= ob %>%
    html_elements(xpath = '//div[contains(@data-attrid,"media presence")]//a') %>%
    html_attr('href') %>% 
    paste0(collapse = "|")
  p2= ob %>%
    html_element(xpath='(//div[@class="kno-rdesc"])[last()]/span[1]/span') %>%
    html_text2()
  data.frame(name=y,desc=p2,links=p1)
}

### Applying the function
out=map2(persons_fix,persons,rhs,.progress = TRUE)

### Merging all dataframes
### Empty values are replaced with NA
output=bind_rows(out) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),~na_if(.x,"")))

Output :


The solution I eventually found is to switch to rvest for html parsing:
  page_source = remDr$getPageSource()
  html_page = read_html(page_source[[1]])
  results = html_page |> html_elements(".kno-vrt-t") |> html_elements("a") |> html_attr("href")

This results correctly in
> results
[1] "https://twitter.com/paologiordano"           "https://www.instagram.com/pg_paologiordano/"

